# Yii2 глючный валидатор файлов

Tags: php, yii2

Есть инпут для загрузки файлов.

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*']) ?>
```

Есть правило в модели

```
[['imageFiles'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 4],
```

Валидация на клиент проходит, все ок. Отправляю на сервер,

```
$model = new Image();
$model->imageFiles = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');
var_dump($model->imageFiles); // получаю массив файлов, здесь все ок.

if ( $model->validate() )
{
    $model->save();
}
```

Несмотря на то что в массиве файлы есть, валидация на сервере не проходит, получаю что нужно загрузить файл.....

Что я не так делаю ?

Comment: посмотрите как проверяеться массив на пустоту в фреймворке. Может вы не в тот массив файлы вставляете. так же проверьте загрузку файлов на сервер.

Comment: Спасибо, с этим разобрался. Теперь проблема с валидацией на клиенте. Не пойму каким образом задать значение атрибуту перед валидацией.

Answer (score 1):

imageFiles у вас массив, поэтому правило нужно создавать такое:

```
[['imageFiles'], 'each', 'rule' => ['file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 4]],
```